# File ownership for file tree php user ID - Folder permission 775

Tags: filesystem

I have the same issue as the below topic, where all my folder are set to 755 but I am unable to run updates or upload new media due to folder permissions. Once I set it to 775, the problem is resolved.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/folder-uploads-permission-to-775/

However, in this thread above it mentioned to *"set ownership of your file tree php user id"*. In my namesco account I have the below FTP accounts:

```
example.com  
example.com_thisisme
```

The website was uploaded using the `example.com_admin`

The owner/group of the files and folders for the website are:

```
example.com_thisisme example.com
```

If I am able to access the files and folders with the `example.com` and reset the permissions to 755. Will this *"set ownership of your file tree php user id"* and also fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If, on your wp-content/uploads directory, 755 doesn't work, but 775 does it means that the **group** example.com already contains the 'php user id', so you don't need to do anything else.

More specifically, the web server process (like apache or nginx) both serves your files and runs PHP, so 'php user id' really means (is the same as) the web server user ID. It has its own user and group just like you have a user and group. If 775 makes things work it means that the web server process is **in** the example.com group.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @mozboz . Is it safe to have all the directories as 775 and the files as 664 ?

Comment: Very much depends on your hosting setup and your needs. I'd suggest main thing is not give write permissions to your web server and directories that don't need it so 775 on directories that need write permission 755 on those that don't and 664 on files seems sensible. (I'm not actually sure if the 'all' permission bit is needed, it might just be convention so if you don't want 'any other user' on your server being able to look at your files you might want 770/750/640 respectively)

Comment: This is not something I am very familiar with. I would prefer if I could use the default permissions. How would I get the webserver to work with 755 folder permissions?